# Ada - Convert File_Size to Integer

Tags: type-conversion, ada

I'm using Ada's Directories library and Command_Line library, and reading the character count (size) of a text file given in the command line, then assigning it to an integer.

```
Character_Count := Size(Argument(1));
```

The compiler is telling me that Integer and File_Size don't match up, even though File_Size is a subtype of Integer, I'm pretty sure. How can I convert it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Ada.Directories.File_Size` is *not* a subtype of `Integer`.

It's defined in the language reference manual as:

```
type File_Size is range 0 .. *implementation-defined*;
```

If you think about it, it wouldn't make much sense for it to be a subtype; `Integer` can be as narrow as 16 bits, which is hardly enough to hold the size of an arbitrary file.

You can use a conversion to convert to Integer:

```
Character_Count := Integer(Size(Argument(1)));
```

but it would probably be much better to declare `Character_Count` as a `File_Size` in the first place.

Comment: Ah, good to know! I do need Character_Count to be an integer, so that conversion is awesome. Thanks so much.

Comment: @user2067941: *Why* do you need `Character_Count` to be an `Integer`? (It's likely that you really don't.)

Comment: @user2067941 - Backing up Keith here. A large part of designing a good Ada program is picking your types carefuly. Do you really have a good reason why you can't just use the type `File_Size` everywhere that value, or something derived from it, is needed? Note that it is quite common these days for files to be larger than 2GB, which is the maximum size that will likely fit in that integer.

Comment: @T.E.D.: Or larger than 32KB, which is the maximum value that's *guaranteed* to fit in that `Integer`. And just to beat the proverbial dead horse, `Character_Count` holds the **Size** of a **File**, which strongly suggests which type it should be.